# Open text file stored as record in Django db

Tags: python, django, django-views

I need to process `.txt` file which has `.csv` structure and is stored as field in database. Main functionality of app is processing this files and generating an output.

Every once in a while I need to upload new version but keep the record of old one. Those are tiny files, rarely exceeding `300kb`. I also need additional fields with uploader's name, date, version etc, that's why I'm keeping it as record in DB rather than in local files.
A file record is stored in DB with type `models.FileField()`

How can I access this record not as a field but as a file object and open it like a usual `.txt`?

What I've tried but it didn't work:

```
listofschedules = ScheduleFile.objects.all
file = listofschedules[0].csvSchedule

with open(file, 'rt', encoding='windows 1250') as csv_input:
      reader = csv.reader(csv_input, delimiter=';')
      print(reader) ...
```

Comment: opening and parsing are the first steps indeed, but how do you expect to display the result ? have you defined a template already ?

Comment: Yes, but for now I'm trying to at least see some kind of confirmation that file opened and trying to use simple print() to log it in terminal window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `all` and then use the file's `path`, as exemplified in [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/files/#using-files-in-models). Or for this simple test you could use `first`:

```
file = ScheduleFile.objects.first().csvSchedule

with open(file.path, 'rt', encoding='windows 1250') as csv_input:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_input, delimiter=';')
    print(reader)
```